# Tomcat 8 does not start immediately after a reboot

Tags: server, restart, tomcat

I have Ubuntu server 15.04 with apt-get installed Tomcat 8. After first launch it starts fine and I can see `XX.XX.XX.XX:8080`, "it works" page. But after `service tomcat8 restart` I should wait about 10 min while this page have to start. Meanwhile `service tomcat8 status` says about success server status.

What's wrong with server? Please help, I really stumped about it.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  The answer for me was in the link provided by Tomasz.  Tomcat is initializing SecureRandom which is really slow.

Workaround is to use a different source of entropy.  You can do this by providing this argument to the tomcat JVM:

```
-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom
```

I did that by creating the setenv.sh script which tomcat will run automatically if it exists:

```
touch /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh
chmod +x /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh
```

Add these lines to setenv.sh and restart the server

```
#!/bin/sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application possibly delays stop (or start) phase. Read these instruction and check the deployed application:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp

If it won't help, there is a problem with Upstart-Tomcat compatibility. Upstart tends to start some less common services too early, which sometimes leads to crashes or other unexpected application behaviours during start.